# Binary Search Tree implementation in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, binary-search

**Please review my BST Code**

**1. Class node**

`class Node:`

**2. Constructor**

```
def __init__(self, data):
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
    self.data = data
```

**3. Insert node**

```
def insert(self, data):
    if self.data:
        if data < self.data:
            if not self.left:
                self.left = Node(data)
            else:
                self.left.insert(data)
        elif data > self.data:
            if not self.right :
                self.right = Node(data)
            else:
                self.right.insert(data)
    else:
        self.data = data
```

**4. Node in delete any value**

```
def getMinValue(self,node):
    current = node
    while(current.left is not None):
        current = current.left
    return current
def delValue(self,data):       
    if data < self.data:
        self.left = self.left.delValue(data)
    elif data > self.data:
        self.right = self.right.delValue(data)
    else:
        if self.left is None:
            temp = self.right
            self = None
            return temp
        elif self.right is None:
            temp = self.left
            self = None
            return temp
        temp = self.getMinValue(self.right)
        self.data = temp.data
        self.right = self.right.delValue(temp.data)
    return self
```

**5. Node in search any value**

```
def getSearchValue(self,data):
    if data == self.data:
        return print(self.data,"True")
    if data < self.data:
        if self.left:
            self.left.getSearchValue(data)   
    if data > self.data:
        if self.right:
            self.right.getSearchValue(data)
```

**6. Print tree**

```
def print_tree(self):
    if self.left:
        self.left.print_tree()
    print(self.data)
    if self.right:
        self.right.print_tree()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You are welcome to also include a little bit of example code in your question and also telling the reviewers about your intention. Did you merely write it to learn Python? etc.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Why did you add [tag:linked-list] as a tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few quick points that came to my mind when looking at your code:

## Documentation

Your code has no documentation whatsoever. Python has so called [documentation strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), which are basically `"""triple quoted text blocks"""` immediately following `def whatever(...)`. Example:

```py
def print_tree(self):
    """Print the content of the tree

    This method performs an in-order traversal of the tree
    """
    # ... your code here
```

Since your question title indicates that you're working with Python 3, also consider using [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) to document your code.

## Naming

There is the infamous [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (aka PEP 8) which recommends to use `lower_case_with_underscores` for variable names and (member) functions. You do this for `print_tree`, but use `camelCase` for the other member functions.

## Searching the tree

Your `getSearchValue` function is a little bit awkward in that it always returns `None`. Although your code promises to "get" the value, you instead print it to the console (together with the string `"True"`) and return the return value of `print` which is `None` (aka no return value in that case). Your function also only returns something (other than the implicit `None`) if the value was found. In my opinion something like

```
def has_value(self, data):
    """Return True or False indicating whether the value is in the BST"""
    if data == self.data:
        return True
    if data < self.data:
        if self.left is not None:
            return self.left.has_value(data)   
    if data > self.data:
        if self.right is not None:
            return self.right.has_value(data)
    return False
```

would be a more appropriate approach. As you can see, this function returns an appropriate bool value to signal the result.

Another minor tweak: this implementation uses `if ... is not None:` to explicitly check for `None` as signaling value. [Since `None` is a singleton in Python, you should always use `is (not)` to check for equality.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)

## Unnecessary parentheses

The parentheses around the condition in `while(current.left is not None):` are not needed. `while` works the same way as `if` in that regard. They are sometimes used for longer conditions that span multiple lines, since Python does implicit line joining in that case.

---

I'm also not fully convinced about your `delValue` function, but unfortunately I'm a little bit short on time at the moment.

Comment: Thank a lot Alex to spent your valuable time to get the review of my code. Let me correct as per your suggestion and get back to you. Today I learned many coding fundamentals and styles from your suggestions. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: Please remember that [it's against the site-policy to change the code in question once you have an answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you have significant improvements over the current version, asking a new question is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
**Code after the suggestion**
```

**1. Class node**

`class Node:`

**2. Constructor**

```
'''this is the constructor'''
def __init__(self, data):
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
    self.data = data
```

**3. Insert node**

```
def insert(self, data):
''' this function work is insert the data in bst'''
    if self.data:
        '''insert left side value '''
        if data < self.data:
            if not self.left:
                self.left = Node(data)
            else:
                self.left.insert(data)
            '''insert right side value'''
        elif data > self.data :
            if not self.right :
                self.right = Node(data)
            else:
                self.right.insert(data)
    else:
        self.data = data
```

**4. Node in delete any value**

```
def getMinValue(self,node):
    '''this fuction work is get minimum value'''
    current = node
    while current.left is not None:
        current = current.left
    return current
def delValue(self,data):       
    '''this fuction work delete value'''
    if data < self.data:
        self.left = self.left.delValue(data)
    elif data > self.data:
        self.right = self.right.delValue(data)
    else:
        if self.left is None:
            temp = self.right
            self = None
            return temp
        elif self.right is None:
            temp = self.left
            self = None
            return temp
        temp = self.getMinValue(self.right)
        self.data = temp.data
        self.right = self.right.delValue(temp.data)
    return self
```

**5. Node in search any value**

```
def getSearchValue(self,data):
    '''this function work finde a value in bst or return True or False'''
    if data == self.data:
        return print(True)
    if data < self.data:
        if self.left:
            self.left.getSearchValue(data)
    if data > self.data:
        if self.right:
            self.right.getSearchValue(data)
        return print(False)
```

**6. Print tree**

```
def printTree(self):
    '''this fuction work print a tree'''
    if self.left:
        self.left.printTree()
    print(self.data)
    if self.right:
        self.right.printTree()
```